# US and CANADA Phone Validation in PHP

Tags: php

My site uses jquery input masking for phone numbers so the pattern is solved already. My pattern is `(123) 456-7890`. Now, I'd like to filter bogus input like (000) 000-0000, (123) 456-7890 and such.

Is there any way to check whether the user input is really a phone number not a bogus/dummy one?

Comment: why do you think that (123) 456-7890 is bogus number?

Comment: Yes, use regular expressions for that. If you want help, please post what you've tried (along with *your* definitions of what is bogus and what is not) :)

Comment: You would probably need to get a list of valid area codes and local exchanges to validate against (if you want to valid more deeply than just the area code).  This is not a regex problem at that point (other than possibly using regex to capture the different parts of the number for validation). I don't know of any solution to validate the entirety of the phone number (i.e. the last 4 digits).

Comment: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/validate-phone-number - A resource for you to start with which includes examples. Not sure if that is entirely complete as it would pass numbers like 555-#### which I *believe* are invalid or something like 911 as area code. There's a lot to consider which you need to do the leg work for.

Comment: many of the users in my site puts (000) 000-0000 as their phone numbers. I'm not sure if regex will fix this but is there a PHP Class out there that handles valid area codes? Thanks for all your responses.

Comment: @acidpaul The question you just asked in your last comment is where YOU need to do some research to find a resource for valid area codes and/or local exchanges.  The resources exist, you just need to Google for them.

Comment: There is no realistic way to verify that a phone number is legit, just as there is no realistic way to verify that an email address is.  As an example, my home phone number ends in -0000, and you would not believe how many websites tell me it's invalid.

Comment: @MarkReed Agreed. I don;t believe it is realistic to validate the entire number.  It is however very simple to validate that the provided area code actually exists and that the local exchange (next 3 digits after area code) exists within that area code.  This will go a long way towards preventing bogus input.  The biggest challenge in implementing such a solution is simply figuring our what you want to use as your source for this data. The actual code implementation is trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at good old PEAR: [`Validate_US`](http://pear.php.net/package/Validate_US/download) package. There is the function:

```
Validate_US::phoneNumber();
```

There is also [`Validate_CA`](http://pear.php.net/package/Validate_CA) for Canada (and other contrys)

Comment: Good suggestion for validating number format.  This however won't solve the problem of validating the validity of the number (i.e. does the area code exist? Does the local exchange exist within that area code?)

Comment: @MikeBrant How will you validate this? Ok, you might validate the area code but whats with the other numbers? You can only validate if you call that number. However, additional validation of the area code might be an improvement. (But I can imagine that in our times it is even possible to get a *fake* area code)

Comment: At a minimum you could validate that an actual area code was provided. Going deeper, you can validate that the local exchange within that area code exists.  This will GREATLY reduce the chance that you get a bogus phone number, as at that point the are only 10000 options left within the local exchange X% of which would be actual phone numbers (obviously X would vary).  I don;t know of a simple way to validate the last portion of the phone number, but my guess is implementing validation on the first two parts will get the OP what he needs (preventing most bogus phone numbers)

Comment: @MikeBrant May I ask if you are coming from US?

Comment: Yes I am in the US.  The list of known area codes and know local exchanges within each area code is absolutely quantifiable.  New area codes are rarely added.  Local exchanges are added with more frequency, but they are also publicly available.

Comment: @MikeBrant Hmmm.. `This will GREATLY reduce the chance that you get a bogus phone number`.. Will it? Berlin's area code is +4930.. I usually type +4930 3030303 (bogus)

Comment: The question was about US and Canadian phone numbers. There are only fixes, known, allowable value for the area code and for the first three digits of the phone number.  This leave only the last 4 digits of the phone number which are specifically mapped to the individual phone subscriber. Sure these last 4 digits could be for an inactive phone number, but at least you make it much harder for a person to just put in a bogus phone number as they have to use a valid area code and local exchange.

Comment: @MikeBrant First, thanks for explaining the US phone number system to me :) didn't know before.. But I still think it is easy to pass an invalid phone number, even an existing one might be the number from another person. Therefore I would not attach too much attention on validating phone numbers - its just untrusted data.. But of course your suggestions are helpful to avoid typos in phone numbers.